# How to get available height in landscape?

Tags: android, height, screen

I have a layout with an imageview. This imageview should have a 4/3 ratio. In portrait mode i get the width of the screen then compute the height and set the imageView dimensions.

```
int[] tailles       = new int[2];
DisplayMetrics dm   = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int widthScreen     = dm.widthPixels;
tailles[0]          = widthScreen;
tailles[1]          = (tailles[0]*3)/4;
```

This part works great.

In landscape mode i need to set the imageView width according to the available height. So i need to get the height of the screen minus the status/notification bar.

I saw the value of 48px for the bar in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116648/how-to-get-the-available-screen-height-minus-navigation-bar-in-honeycomb). Is it a standard size ?

What the best solution to get the available height regardless of the used device ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, that you cannot do with standard layout? It is highly discouraged to use pixel-based dimensioning in Android.

Comment: The image displayed in the imageview is send by a server. The server need to know the resolution (in pixel) before building and sending it to the phone. That's why i need to use px and not unit like dip or dp

Comment: Then my advice is to lay out your view with a "Waiting for the server" image. Measure the image's width and height, and then send the request to the server with the retrieved dimensions.

Of course this way you will not be able to pre-cache landscape sized images if in portait mode. But your solution will be flexible: if a new UI component (toolbar, title-label...) is introduced, or the Activity is refactored to run in full screen, you won't have anything to modify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're creating an Activity, than you have to have some sort of layout. Get it's root component, and retrieve it's size (getWidth, getHeight). That'll be the available width and height without counting the status bar.

Comment: Furthermore, getWidth() and getHeight() are not available until the layout is completed (which is often after onResume() fires)

Answer (score 2):

```
    Display d = ((Activity) mContext).getWindowManager()
            .getDefaultDisplay();
    int h = d.getHeight();
    int w = d.getWidth();
```

in portrait h > w and in landscape w > h